# Unzipping a batch of files

Tags: command-line, zip

When I try

```
 unzip filename.zip
```

it works. However, I need to unzip a series of zip files.

Why are:

```
 find . -name "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 unzip
```

or

```
 ls *.zip | xargs unzip
```

not working?

In both cases I get a "caution: filename not matched: " message.

Answer (score 51):

You can issue the command:

```
$ unzip '*.zip'
```

Look here for [reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-unzipping-many-zip-files/).

Comment: I didn't say it clearly, but they are not all in the same directory. So, I need the output of find.

Comment: Thanks. This might nit match the actual question perfectly but this solved my problem. I was trying `unzip *` and it returned `caution: filename not matched` for every file but `unzip '*.zip'` did the job.

Answer (score 31):

Your commands are not working because they stuff all the files onto the same command line. While that works with most programs, `unzip` will take the first argument as the zip file, and any after the first as files to extract from it. You need to execute the command once for each file:

```
find . -name "*.zip" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 unzip
```

Or

```
find . -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {} \;
```

Comment: The second one seems to be better in case there really are a lot of files. (Otherwise it complained the command is too long with xargs)

Answer (score 6):

In bash you could also do the following:

```
for i in *.zip; do
    unzip "$i"
done
```

Also `unzip` can take the `-d` switch so you can target the output to different locations.

For example:

```
uzdir=/path/to/unzips
for i in *.zip; do
    [ -d "$uzdir/$i" ] || mkdir -p "$uzdir/$i"
    unzip "$i" -d "$uzdir/$i"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier solution than the looping ones given above, use the directory `-d` flag:

```
unzip -o somefiles.zip -d $directoryPath
```

Comment: `-d` specifies the dir to extract into, not the dir to look in for files.